AccountNotInitialized when using an AccountLoader in a PDA
I don't understand something, when I get a PDA, this code is working totally fine:
    #[account()]
    pub token_mint: Account<'info, Mint>,

    #[account(
        mut,
        seeds = [
            TOKEN_VAULT_SEED.as_bytes(),
            token_mint.key().as_ref(),
        ],
        bump
    )]
    pub token_vault: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,

But if I use the value inside the account loader:
    #[account()]
    pub vault: AccountLoader<'info, VaultState>,
    
    #[account(
        mut,
        seeds = [
            TOKEN_VAULT_SEED.as_bytes(),
            vault.load()?.token_mint.as_ref(),
        ],
        bump
    )]
    pub token_vault: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,

I get
Program log: AnchorError caused by account: token_vault. Error Code: AccountNotInitialized. Error Number: 3012. Error Message: The program expected this account to be already initialized.'

Init part
    #[account(
        init,
        seeds =[
            TOKEN_VAULT_SEED.as_bytes(),
            token_mint.key().as_ref(),
        ],
        bump,
        payer = admin,
        token::mint = token_mint,
        token::authority = vault,
        token::token_program = token_program,
    )]
    pub token_vault: Box<InterfaceAccount<'info, TokenAccount>>

Vault state
#[account(zero_copy(unsafe))]
pub struct VaultState {
    /// Bump to identify PDA
    pub bump: [u8; 1],
    // Token used to buy
    pub token_mint: Pubkey,
    // Token vault
    pub token_vault: Pubkey,
}

Even if vault.load()?.token_mint is litteraly the same pubkey than the one passed from token_mint, are using dynamic value from an accountloader in PDA forbidden?
Thanks for your help
